# Neo4j: Cypher Performance testing/Benchmarking

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created a Neo4j 3 database that includes some test data and also a small application that will send http cypher requests to Neo4j. These requests are always of the same time. Acutally its a query template that just differs by some attributes. I am interested in the performance of these statements.
I know that I can use the `PROFILE` to get some information in the browser. But I want to execute a set of statements, e. g. 10 example queries, several times and calculate the average performance. Is there an easy way or a tool to do this or do I have to write e. g. a Python script that collects these values? It does not have to be a big application, I just want to see some general performance metrics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box tool for benchmarking Neo4j yet. So your best option is to implement your own solution - but you have to be careful if you want to get results that are (to some degree) representative:

1. Check the [docs on performance](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/).
2. Give the Neo4j JVM sufficient time to warmup. This means that you'll want to run a warmup phase with the queries and discard the execution times of them.
3. Instead of using a client-server architecture, you can also opt to use Neo4j in embedded mode, which will give you a better idea of the query performance (without the overhead of the driver and the serialization/deserialization process). However, in this case you have to implement benchmark over the JVM (in Java or possibly Jython).
4. Run each query multiple times. **Do not use the average** as it is more sensitive to outlier values (you can get high values for a number of reasons, e.g. if the OS scheduler starts some job in the background during a particular query execution).

   A good paper in the topic, [How not to lie with statistics: the correct way to summarize benchmark results](https://scholar.google.hu/scholar?cluster=8793337438520474692), argues that you should use the geometric mean.

   It is also common practice in performance experiments in computer science papers to use the median value. I tend to use this option - e.g. this figure shows the execution times of two simple SPARQL queries on in-memory RDF engines (Jena and Sesame), for their first executions and the median values of 5 consecutive executions.

   [image]
5. Note however, that Neo4j employs various caching mechanisms, so if you only run the same query multiple times, it will only need to compute the results on the first execution and following executions will use the cache - unless the database is updated between the query executions.
6. As a good approximation, you can design the benchmark to resemble your actual workload as closely as possible - in many cases, [application-specific macrobenchmarks make more sense than microbenchmarks](https://www.eecs.harvard.edu/margo/papers/hotos99-2/paper.pdf). So if each query will only be evaluated once by the application, it is perfectly acceptable to benchmark only the first evaluation.
7. (Bonus.) Another good read in the topic is [The Benchmark Handbook](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/gray/BenchmarkHandbook/TOC.htm) - chapter 1 discusses the most important criteria for domain-specific benchmarks (relevance, portability, scalability and simplicity). These are probably not required for your benchmark but these are nice to now.

I worked on a cross-technology benchmark considering relational, graph and semantic databases, including Neo4j. You might find some useful ideas or code snippets in the repository: https://github.com/FTSRG/trainbenchmark

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. This is very helpful. I want the Neo4j performance for my configuration. So what about using the same environment, i. e. access via bolt driver etc, looping over 10 or 20 different queries and write out timestamps. I know this is a bit basic but I want to know some general values that I can show the approx. time consumption for Neo4j and the processing in my application. Then I could calculate the execution time of Neo4j per statement and then I could use the median etc.

Comment: @Stefan I think you concept is basically okay, but I suspect Neo4j still might cache the results so I'd recommend to plot the data (with Excel sheets or Python/R scripts) - this will show if there are any suspicious data records.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Is there a way to avoid caching? I dont have that much data, so actually the whole graph would fit into the RAM. But the query is quite complex and therefore I want to see how much time is needed for the execution...

Comment: One quick-and-dirty solution would be to implement a Java application and use the [ImpermanentGraphDatabase](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-unit-testing) of Neo4j. This allows you to create a new database for each query, while (hopefully) still being able to warmup the JVM. Also, if you are aiming to measure large, characteristic performance differences (e.g. 1-2 orders of magnitude), you do not need to be super finicky about the benchmark details - if a query is 10-100x times slower in real-life, the benchmark will probably show a significant difference.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. But its not that easy in my case. I use a application that comunicates with Neo4j via REST and a Python script (just for my prototype) that uses bolt. Furthermore I need specific data in the database. That means I have to execute 1000s of statements via code before I can start with the actual test. I really appreciate your help but I am not sure if this would work in my case.

Comment: Fully deactivating the caches is also no solution, that would show a much higher response time as usual I guess...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! Ok, for my case that would mean that the best way would be to simulate a workload as it would occur during the regular operation. And it would be better to execute each query just once, even if I could provide just a few instead of executing the same queries in a loop. Create such a full hybrid approach is a way to oversized for me and I could not compare it with other systems. But the general idea is to simulate the real normal usage of the system.

Comment: Yes - I agree with your conclusion. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was a big help for me! :)